# An Efficient way to calculate sum of absolute difference between two Arrays?

Tags: algorithm, statistics

I have have two arrays A and B which can contain any positive or negative integer.
I want to calculate the sum of absolute difference which is given as

[image: $\sum_i^p\sum_j^q|Pi-Qj|]

where p and q are sizes of Array P and Q respectively.

lets see an Example
if

```
  P = [2, 4] and Q = [4, -3, -4, 4].

    = |2 - 4| + | 2 - (-3) | + |2 - (-4) | + | 2 - 4 | + | 4 - 4 | + | 4 - (-3) | + 
       | 4 - (-4) | + | 4 - 4 | 

    = 2 + 5 + 6 + 2 + 0 + 7 + 8 + 0 
                   = 30
```

Is there any efficient way of doing ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also do you have a language preference?

Answer (score 1):

```
[2, 4] [4, -3, -4, 4]
```

Sorted: `[2, 4] [-4, -3, 4, 4]`

```
qs are negative, p is positive:
2 + 4 + 2 + 3 = sum(4, 3) + 2*2

qs are larger than p:
4 - 2 + 4 - 2 = sum(4, 4) - 2*2

qs are negative, p is positive:
4 + 4 + 4 + 3 = sum(4, 3) + 2*4

qs are equal to p:
4 - 4 + 4 - 4 = 0


qs are smaller than p (not in our example):
5 - 3 + 5 - 2 = -sum(3, 2) + 2*5

qs and p are both negative (not in our example):
  p is larger:
  |-5 - (-7)| + |-5 - (-6)| = 7 - 5 + 6 - 5 = sum(7, 6) - 2*5
  q is larger:
  |-5 - (-3)| + |-5 - (-2)| = 5 - 3 + 5 - 2 = -sum(3, 2) + 2*5

p is negative, qs are positive (not in our example):
|7 - (-5)| + |6 - (-5)| = 7 + 5 + 6 + 5 = sum(7, 6) + 2*5
```

There are a few cases here, all of which can reuse already computed sums, as well as multiplication, if the arrays are ascending.

Sort and compute a prefix-sum array for `Q`, also recording the index where `q`s turn to positive if there is one. For each `p` find the start and end section of each case described above in either `O(log n)` or `O(1)` time. Add to the total by using the prefix-sum and a multiple of `p`. Complexity: `O(n log n)` time, `O(n)` space.

Comment: Why does it matter the sign of p/q? If `p>q` the absolute difference is `p-q`; otherwise it is `q-p`.

Comment: @rici Not sure - can you come up with a formula just for those two cases you described that uses the prefix sum and a multiplication without observing the signs? I may have missed that redundancy. I guess my answer is more about the principle of the thing more than the exact reduction :)

Comment: If you're adding them all up, then each `p` appears positively the number of times it is greater than some `q` and negatively the number of times it is not. And similarly for the `q`s, although you need to use `>=` instead of `>`. So all you need to know is the rank of each element amongst the elements of the other vector; you could get that by sorting both vectors abd doing a merge.

Comment: @rici nice reduction!

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not be more efficient to add or subtract the (unmodified) difference depending on sign instead of ("unconditionally") "adding `abs()`".
I'd expect a contemporary compiler, even JIT, to detect the equivalence, though.

```
! Sum of Absolute Differences between every pair of elements of two arrays;
INTEGER PROCEDURE SAD2(a, b);
    INTEGER ARRAY a, b;
BEGIN
    INTEGER sum, i, j;  ! by the book, declare j locally just like diff;
    sum := 0;
    FOR i := LOWERBOUND(a, 1) STEP 1 UNTIL UPPERBOUND(a, 1) DO
        FOR j := LOWERBOUND(b, 1) STEP 1 UNTIL UPPERBOUND(b, 1) DO BEGIN
            INTEGER diff;
            diff := a(i) - b(j);
            sum := if diff < 0 then sum - diff
                               else sum + diff;
        END;
    SAD2 := sum;
END SAD2;
```

For a sub-quadratic algorithm, see [גלעד ברקן's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48239655/3789665).
This may well be code for what גלעד ברקן intended, not following to PEP8 to the dot:

```python
''' Given sequences A and B, SAD2 computes the sum of absolute differences
 for every element b from B subtracted from every element a from A.

The usual SAD sums up absolute differences of pairs with like index, only.
'''
from bisect import bisect_right

class state(list):
    ''' Hold state for one sequence: sorted elements & processing state. '''
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.extend(sorted(a))
        self.total = 0
        ''' sum(self[:self.todo]) '''
        self.todo = 0
        ''' next index to do/#elements done '''
    def __str__(self):
        return list.__str__(self) + str(self.todo) + ', ' + str(self.total)

def SAD2(a, b):
    ''' return Sum of Absolute Differences of all pairs (a[x], b[y]). '''
    nPairs = len(a) * len(b)
    if nPairs < 2:
        return abs(a[0] - b[0]) if 0 < nPairs else None
    a = state(a)
    b = state(b)
    sad = 0
    while True:
        key = a[a.todo]
        identical = bisect_right(a, key, a.todo)
        local = 0
        # iterate 'til not lower
        # going to need i: no takewhile(lambda x: x < key, b[todo:])
        i = b.todo
        while i < len(b):
            val = b[i]
            if key <= val:
                break
            local += val
            i += 1
        # update SAD
        # account for elements in a[:a.todo] paired with b[b.todo:i]
        sad += local*a.todo - a.total*(i - b.todo)
        b.todo = i
        n_key = identical - a.todo
        local += b.total
        b.total = local
        # account for elements in a[a.todo:identical] paired with b[:i]
        sad += (key*i - local)*n_key
        if len(b) <= b.todo:
            rest = len(a) - identical
            if 0 < rest:
                sad += sum(a[identical:])*len(b) - b.total*rest
            return sad
        a.todo = identical
        a.total += key * n_key
        a, b = b, a
```